# Fade the bottom of a div over a semi-transparent background

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing text placed over a semi-transparent background.
I would like the bottom of this div to gradually disappear.

I used a gradient to achieve this.  Over a non-semi-transparent background it works without any problem.

```
#fadeout {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I made this fiddler showing what I want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/ytuxn9Lu/6/ (link edited to add random background image, see edit)

The problem is that the gradiant overlay adds with the background and so the result is not what I want.

What can I do to achieve this ?

Thanks !

EDIT:  To add more information, in the real application, the `body` has an image background.  The `#parent` div has a semi-transparent background and the `#fadeout-parent` div contains the text and the `fadeout` div.
The solution sould then work no matter the background color/image (if possible).

Comment: Instead of using white(255) RGB on the gradient, use the white at 70% RGB instead(179): https://jsfiddle.net/ytuxn9Lu/4/

Comment: Thanks @APAD1, however, it seems to work on a black background, but if you change the color (for blue for instance), it still show the div as before.

Comment: Could you explain what your requirement is for the background, then? Is it safe to assume you want this to be able to work above _any_ color?

Comment: Well in the real case I'm using an image as background, so yes, it should work for any color (if possible of course !)

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution here

https://jsfiddle.net/hgtdwbrL/1/

I just changed the values of the gradient (used a color picker to get the color from below the content and added 0.9 transparency):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.9) 95%);
```

Comment: As I sait it in the comments, it will only work against a black background, but in the real application, the background is an image.  I added information about this in the post just now. Thanks !

Comment: well, in this case (fading against a background image) it would be necessary to influence the *text color*. I remember there are some JS plugings that allow to fill the letter shapes of the text with an image, so that might be a solution (using the same image as for the background), but I've never tried that so far.

Answer (score 2):

I think the perfect way to achieve this does not currently exist..

So, there's Yet Another Tricky Solution : mine

https://jsfiddle.net/ytuxn9Lu/9/

```
(code seems to be mandatory when posting jsfiddle link)
```

Comment: This is not yet perfect, if you change the background to use a solid color (e.g. red) you'll notice that the opacity is more opaque at the bottom than in the top

Answer (score 2):

I found something that can work:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/900/600?random);
  padding: 50px;
}
#parent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  padding: 20px;
}
#fadeout-parent {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(0.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.35, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.50, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.65, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="fadeout-parent">
      <h1>An h1 header</h1>

      <p>Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.</p>

      <p>2nd paragraph. <em>Italic</em>, <strong>bold</strong>, and <code>monospace</code>. Itemized lists look like:</p>

      <ul>
        <li>this one</li>
        <li>that one</li>
        <li>the other one</li>
      </ul>

      <p>Note that --- not considering the asterisk --- the actual text content starts at 4-columns in.</p>

      <blockquote>
        <p>Block quotes are written like so.</p>

        <p>They can span multiple paragraphs, if you like.</p>
      </blockquote>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

It has a downside, browser compatibility. I works in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Not exactly, the semi-transparent background has to stay the way it is in the example, only the text should dim.

Answer (score 1):

If im barking up the wrong tree please forgive me.

If you are just trying to fade the text out within the div you could just change to:

```
#parent {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

If you want the background div to fade out also you could try putting a gradient color on that div. Maybe remove the

```
<div id="fadeout"></div>
```

altogether.

Comment: The problem is that I need it to work with a semi-transparent background.  Setting it to white does indeed work, but it is not what I mean to do.